# Using STR_TO_DATE with insert

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, insert

I have a test table in my database with the following structure: id(PK, Auto_Increment), dataI(datetime), dataF (datetime).

Using MySQL Workbench, when I try to insert a record I am having problems. I tried different ways using str_to_date to fix it.

```
INSERT INTO test(dataI, dataF) 
VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('2020-01-10 18:00:00', '%YYYY-%MM-%DD hh:mm:ss'), STR_TO_DATE('2020-01-10 24:00:00', '%YYYY-%MM-%DD hh:mm:ss'))
```

> Error code 1411: Incorrect datetime value for function str_to_date

Comment: Review date format here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'24:00:00'` is ***not*** a valid time component for a DATETIME literal.

---

The format specification must match the string. The list of valid specifiers is documented under the `DATE_FORMAT` function, which is referenced under the documentation for the `STR_TO_DATE` function on the same page.

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Format of that first value could be specified as `'%Y-%m-%d %h %H:%i:%s'`

or more concisely as `'%Y-%m-%d %T'`

We don't need to use `STR_TO_DATE` function when date literals are supplied in the default format; MySQL will do the conversion to DATETIME implicitly.

---

We could do this:

```
... VALUES ('2020-01-10 18:00:00','2020-01-11 00:00:00')
```

Or, if we want to use the `STR_TO_DATE`, we specify a format that matches our string

```
... VALUES( STR_TO_DATE('2020-01-10 18:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %T')
          , STR_TO_DATE('2020-01-11 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %T')
          )
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your format strings are wrong. For example, `%YYYY` should just be `%Y`; `%YYYY` means a 4-digit year followed by the literal string `YYY`.

The format strings should be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s`.

See the complete list of format directives [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).